# Why is there an ambiguity with Dapper QueryAsync when used with MiniProfiler?

Tags: c#, dapper, miniprofiler, .net-core-2.2

EDIT **1**:
When trying to call the extension method explicitly:

```
Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryAsync<dynamic>(cnx, "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.Company;");
```

I have a much more explicit error message:

> The type 'SqlMapper' exists in both 'Dapper.StrongName, Version=1.50.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e3e8412083d25dd3' and 'Dapper, Version=1.50.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Can I do something about it ?

Dapper.StrongName is a dependency of MiniProfiler (.Net standard 1.5)

---

I'm trying to use MiniProfiler alongside Dapper to see SQL commands send to the backend.

I have the following code to produce an instrumented connection on demand:

```
   private static DbConnection GetCnx(bool instrumented = false)
    {
        var cnx = new SqlConnection("Data Source=foo;Initial Catalog=bar;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        // Enabling statistics for logging purposes
        if (instrumented)
            return new ProfiledDbConnection(cnx, MiniProfiler.Current);
        else
            return cnx;
    }
```

The following consuming code won't compile anymore:

```
using (DbConnection cnx = GetCnx())
{
      await cnx.OpenAsync();
      return await cnx.QueryAsync<dynamic>("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.Company;");
}
```

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryAsync(System.Data.IDbConnection, string, object, System.Data.IDbTransaction, int?, System.Data.CommandType?)' and 'Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryAsync(System.Data.IDbConnection, string, object, System.Data.IDbTransaction, int?, System.Data.CommandType?)'

The ambiguous methods are identical, unless I need a new pair of glass.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the Dapper.StrongName nuget instead of Dapper.

Answer (score 0):

One can also remove the existing explicitly included nuget reference to Dapper and go with what gets installed as a dependecy of MiniProfiler storage providers.